# Good book for numerical methods for solving for the nash equilibrium

Tags: numerical-methods, game-theory

I'm looking for a good book that describes numerical methods for game theory. Something complete, with detailed proofs, that has as little prerequisites as possible. Any suggestions ?

Comment: "Finite dimensional variational inequalities and complementarity problems"

Comment: Just started reading it. Looks great ! Thank you.